# Removing hog taste from pork

Tags: pork

My niece married a man from Mexico and he wants her to make her pork chops not taste like hog.  I suggested marinating them in lime juice and season with some Mexican seasoning.  Do you think this will work?

Comment: related: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/104307/what-is-the-porky-taste-in-certain-types-of-pork and https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/is-there-a-way-to-prep-mutton-in-order-to-ease-its-strong-flavor/2937#2937

Comment: Welcome to the site. I'm not sure what you mean by 'taste like hog'.